# Trying to get property of non-object wordpress error message

Tags: plugins, php, errors, notices

I am running the really-simple-facebook-twitter-share-buttons.  I have placed the below code on my site as the plug in recommends, which is:

```
<div class="share"><?php echo really_simple_share_publish();?></div>
```

This plugin is working on all of my site, except I have a custom taxonomy page that is causing the following error with the plugin:

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home3/answr/public_html/wp-includes/post-template.php on line 29

I have reviewed line 29 and here is what I think is happening.

My taxonomy page has two main custom queries built into it and two wordpress loops.  These queries modify the main wordpress query for the page.

It seems if the first query does not return results then it causes the error above if the plugin is active.

However, if the first query returns results then there is no error and the plugin works fine even if the second query returns results.

And if the plugin is not active I get no error whether the first query returns results or not.

Here is my code for reference.  I have been trying to solve this for some time and I am out of ideas.  Does anyone have ideas what could be causing this issues or what I should try to solve it.  Thank you!

```
<?php

    query_single('dealers', 'publish', '1', $taxtype, $value);
?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php 

$address=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-street_address', TRUE); 
$city=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-city', TRUE); 
$state=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-state_abbreviation', TRUE); 
$zip=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-zip_code', TRUE); 
$phone=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-phone_number', TRUE); 
$paid=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-paid', TRUE);
$post_id=get_the_ID();
get_each_dealer_brand($post_id);?>

<?php 
echo "<ul class=\"ullisting\">";
if($paid==1)
{
    echo "<li><p class=\"plisting\"><strong><a href=\"";the_permalink(); echo "\">";the_title();echo "</a></strong></p></li>";
    echo "<li><p class=\"plisting\">$address | $city, $state $zip</p></li>";
    echo "<li><p class=\"plisting\">P: $phone</p></li>";
        echo "<li><p class=\"listing\"><span><small>$brands_list</small></span></p></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php

wp_reset_query(); 
wp_reset_postdata(); 
unset($brands_list);
?>

<?php else : ?>

<?php


$paidnull="true";
?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php

    query_single('dealers', 'draft', '0', $taxtype,  $value);
?>


<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>



<?php $address=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-street_address', TRUE);
$city=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-city', TRUE);
$state=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-state_abbreviation', TRUE);
$zip=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-zip_code', TRUE);
$phone=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-phone_number', TRUE);
$paid=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-paid', TRUE);
$post_id=get_the_ID();
get_each_dealer_brand($post_id);
?>


<?php 
echo "<ul class=\"ullisting\">";
if($paid==0){
    echo "<li><p class=\"plisting\"><strong>";the_title();echo "</strong></p></li>";
    echo "<li><p class=\"plisting\">$address | $city, $state $zip</p></li>";
    echo "<li><p class=\"plisting\">P: $phone</p></li>";
        echo "<li><p class=\"listing\"><span><small>$brands_list</small></span></p></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php /*Resets current query*/
wp_reset_query(); 
wp_reset_postdata(); 
unset($brands_list);?>

<?php else : ?>

<?php /*If there were no paid dealer and no non-paid dealers we must show a 404 error*/
if ($paidnull=="true")
{
    echo "<h1 class=\"title\">There Are No Dealers Found for your Search</h1>";
    echo "<p style=\"color:#F30\">Use the search below to search a different area</p>";
    echo "<br />";
}?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: If you rewrite so that you are not clobbering the main query does it work?

Comment: @s_ha_dum I assume you mean if I leave the original wordpress query in place.  It does work in this instance.  But that is not an option on this custom taxonomy page.  I need a custom query.  And when that query actually returns results I don't get the error message.  But when the query has no result the error message happens.  And that error only happens when the plugin is active.  If the plugin is not active no error notice.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Given that the page works if you leave the original query alone, your solution is pretty simple. Leave the original query alone. You don't need to overwrite that query in order to created secondary loops. Instead of this:

```
query_single('dealers', 'publish', '1', $taxtype, $value);
if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : 
        the_post();
```

You want:

```
$myq = new WP_Query($args);
if ($myq->have_posts()) :
    while ($myq->have_posts()) : 
        $myq->the_post();
```

You can do that as many times as you want on the page and not clobber the main query. The catch is that I don't know what `single_query` is and so I don't know exactly what `$args` should look like. Given the way the code works I suspect that `single_query` runs [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts), which is strongly discouraged. It could just as easily return a new `WP_Query` object for you to use, if you tweaked it.

### Reference

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: thank you again for the explanation.  I tried but  still getting the error.  Here is what I think is causing the error.  In my custom taxonomy all of my posts are set to draft.  If the meta field is set to paid then the post will be set to publish. May custom taxonomy page will find this post in this query `query_single('dealers', 'publish', '1', $taxtype, $value);` which is a new wordpress query not query_posts.  The error is not actually happening due to no results in query.  The error happens because there are no post in my taxonomy set to published.

Comment: I also confirmed the above on my main home page.  If I have 1 post published the plugin is fine.  But if no posts are in my system it errors.  Since my custom taxonomy page publishes drafts not published posts I get the error on that page of my site but not other pages of my site.  Now I just have to find out where to fix the plugin.

Comment: It looks like `query_single` does not return an object and since your code mostly works, does `query_single` overwrite the global `$wp_query` variable?